# How can i reinitialize owl.carousel when i open modal again?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, owl-carousel

I have page like album. When anyone click on that album then i should display their inner image in modal using owl.carousel. Help me to solve out this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the event 'shown.bs.modal' to trigger the code
2. Normally you can call the method 'refresh' to renew your carousel.

   ```
   $('#idModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel('refresh');
    })
   ```

You could always empty the div and add a whole new carousel as well.